# Is there any way to have several open terminal windows with different themes?

Tags: command-line, themes, xubuntu

I am used to OSX which lets you do this, and its very usefult to me because I always have at least three terminals, so having a different look for each makes my work easier.

Also, is it possible to download terminal 'themes', or I have to manually define the styles from the terminal options?

P.D: I am using a Xubuntu environment

Answer (score 4):

To open a new terminal with a different profile, use File->Open Terminal->Profile name.

[image]

You can edit the different profiles under Edit->Profiles..., or just edit the current profile with Edit->Profile Preferences.

[image]

Comment: That looks great, but I cant seem to find the option in my Xubuntu environment. Is that environment-specific?

Comment: @oalo Hmm, I didn't realize you were on Xfce. This is gnome-terminal. You might be able to install it on Xfce. Not sure.